# World Wall Map, mouse hover information

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image of the World Wall Map, now when I hover over specific cities I want to be able to show the latitude and longitude and the date and time at the location.

I would prefer jQuery, if there is any alternative or existing stuff that could help, please let me know.

Comment: What have you looked in to doing?

Comment: This sounds like a cool project.  What have you done so far?

Comment: Folks, I just woke up in the middle of the night and came up with idea, and since I have done work on jQuery, figured someone should have done something like this, but searched and nothing +ve came up, so here I am asking for help.... http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html

Comment: My basic idea is to create a widget, so important cities can be displayed with temperature and on mouse hover, show the other details which can be configured.

Comment: So do you want us to develop all that? :D You question was about how to hover certain map elements and display information. You can use MapHighlight with e.g. an json objects that holds you data and asign that data to the areas on the map.

Comment: I don't won't anyone to develop it, since @Groovetrain mentioned it as a cool project, just thought I'd give a brief idea abt the idea, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this example

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

which is realized with this jQuery plugin

[**jQuery MapHighlight**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com) for that.